# Catalytic hydrogenation of Benzene

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

Why is Benzene not hydrogenated when a side group is catalytically hydrogenated? Some books say that the Benzene ring is also hydrogenated, others say the opposite.

Comment: It depends on the conditions - catalyst used, hydrogen pressure etc. The aromatic system makes the double bonds particularly resistant to reduction, but it can be done with the correct choice of conditions  see https://www.chemengonline.com/cyclohexane-production-benzene-hydrogen/